# Look for running processes without supervisor

Tags: php, laravel, centos

Is there a way to look for all processes without supervisor on laravel app? Something that can be used to make GUI page with info about everything and where I could apply auto start, restart etc..

So I am wondering is there any command that looks for all processes in real time that can output data or do I need to run same command over and over again?

Happy new year!

Comment: Not a Laravel user, but there is always `$processes = shell_exec('ps aux | grep php')`. Well unless your on shared hosting and they disable `shell` commands.

Comment: I have vps I am just building some admin panel in laravel for my vps and other sites. I run there laravel echo server which sometimes stop working so it needs autorestart etc.. So the best way would be to run `$schedule->exec('ps aux | grep php')->everyMinute();` but I need to push that to the client side which also needs laravel echo for listening.. So I guess best way would be to send ajax request each min or what do you think? @ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: Well, normally you'd use the `laravel-echo-server` to push the update to the browser. But in your case, polling could be more appropriate...

Comment: But what speaks against using `systemd` instead of `supervisor` if it's not available?